# Where delphi take the value of $(JDKPath)?

Tags: delphi

In delphi their is a variable **$(JDKPath)**, we can use it for exemple in Post Build event command line ... however i don't understand from where delphi take the value of $(JDKPath). In my computer it's always point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" but in options i see no settings to configure it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an "[Environment Variable](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28254)". You can configure them by going to:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Environment Options` > `Environment Variables`.

They are essentially just pre-defined directories which can be used in various places across Delphi, most commonly in library and browsing paths.

This particular one is an Android / Java SDK directory. Again, it's just a unique name which represents a particular directory on your computer for Delphi to know where to find certain files - it's just configured in a different place. In this particular case, it appears to be automatically generated based on what was selected under the `Java` section of the SDK configuration.

Comment: Thanks jerry, no it's was not this. Strangely it's a variable that it's bound to the android SDK configuration, but you CAN'T edit it (no field for edit it), BUT you can set it when you create a new android SDK configuration! i guess it's was forgotten by emb to add this field for edition. It's even more strange that this variable is not fixed, for exemple on seattle i have jdk1.8 and on berlin i have jdk1.7. i will open a bug request at emb to be able to edit this field

Comment: yes, it's like an environment viariable, it's configured in the regedit, but their is no way to edit it in Delphi :( the only way is to add a new android SDK configuration

Comment: Thank you loki, this hint solved some issues for me. I was able to edit the JDKPath settings in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\<Delphi Version, i.e. 18.0>\PlatformSDKs\